Destructive @_ operation and passing @_ in the same statement
I'm looking for perl docs confirming the following behaviour, where passed @_ still holds the first argument, despite shift() which alters @_.
use Data::Dumper;
sub f { shift->(@_) }

f(sub{ print Dumper \@_ }, 1,2);

output
$VAR1 = [
      sub { "DUMMY" },
      1,
      2
    ];


That expression passed to the sub is first processed at the point of call (before the call happens where @_ is processed), which is when print runs.  So @_ could have not been changed yet. Perhaps our "normal" sub call behavior so I don't know that this would be in docs specifically?

perl -wE'sub tt { shift(@_); say "@_" }; tt(1, 2, my $x = print "hi")'
This prints hi2 1  (the 1 is for success of print)

I would expect there is at least some reference to the behaviour as it kinda breaks DWIM principle.

Yeah, it's a good example you came up with.  But I think that the processing of what's in those parens is how @_ is built, in general, so that's just that.

You are asking about the order in which the shift is performed relative to creation of the argument list.
It's not documented.
Rely on this at your own risk, but Perl always evaluates the left of the -> last in a call (so that the code reference is topmost on the stack).
In the following, you can see that @_ (lines 3 and 4) is evaluated before shift (line 5).
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec,f -e'
use Data::Dumper;
sub f { shift->(@_) }
f(sub{ print Dumper \@_ }, 1,2);
'
main::f:
1  <;> nextstate(main 1266 -e:3) v
2  <0> pushmark s
3  <#> gv[*_] s
4  <1> rv2av[t2] lKM/1
5  <0> shift s*
6  <1> entersub[t3] KS/TARG
7  <1> leavesub[1 ref] K/REFC,1
-e syntax OK

Let's walk through it.

Let's say that @_ initially contains scalars A, B and C.
Line 2 marks the stack.
Lines 3 and 4 places scalars A, B and C on the stack.
Line 5 then places A on the stack. (It now contains four scalars since the mark.) It also shifts the contents of @_ so that it now contains B and C.
Line 6 calls the sub identified by the topmost scalar on the stack, A. The remaining scalars added since the mark (A, B and C) are provided to the sub as arguments.

Solution: Avoid reading and modifying the same variable in the same expression.
sub f { $_[0]->( @_[ 1 .. $#_ ] ) }

sub f { my $cb = shift; $cb->( @_ ) }

sub f { my $cb = shift; &$cb }

sub f { &{ +shift } }

Or if you want to remove the stack frame for f from the stack (hiding it from caller and croak), you can use the following:
sub f { my $cb = shift; goto &$cb }


sub f { return $_->(@_) for shift } also comes to mind.

Re:@mpapec that clobbers the return value – ikegami that would be the case without the explicit return, http://tpcg.io/_WQNLSS

@mappec, Sorry, wasn't awake

but Perl always evaluates the left of the -> last in a call (so that the code reference is topmost on the stack).
TIL. Thank you.

perl also strongly endorses DWIM. Just saying.

@mpapec, When you both modify and read something in the same expression, there rarely any clear intended meaning. Even here. It makes perfect sense to me that the left of ->() is evaluated after the argument list in stack-based machine (which is basically all of them).

I wouldn't defend that, as reading from left shift occurs first before passing the @_

@mappec, What's that got to do with anything. There's a million examples of things not happening from left to right, starting with f "a" / f( "a" ) / *f->( "a" ). "a" is evaluated before *f and the call. Why should the order be different for $f->( "a" )???

make a survey for DWIM on this particular question and you'll get the answer whether it's correct.

don't know about that, but I know easy things should be easy, hard things should be possible, and DWIM. these are some of the principles perl explicitly adheres to.

@mappec, What people might expect isn't correct no matter what they expect. Because it's not a matter of expectations. Changing a variable and using it in the same expression is wrong.

@mpapec, No, it's literally not possible to call a function before computing its argument list. f "a" cannot be done from left-to-right. I didn't say hard; I said impossible.

Any expression passed to the sub is first processed, at the point of call (before the call happens, which is where the resulting @_ itself is processed).  Thus this is when print runs.  So this really goes before the actual @_ is constructed and thus it could have not been changed yet.
This is perhaps our "normal" sub call behavior so I don't know that it would be in docs specifically.
A command-line ("one-liner")  example:
perl -wE'sub tt { shift(@_); say "@_" }; tt(1, 2, my $x = print "hi")'

This prints
hi2 1

(the 1 is for success of print)
The expression in the question defines an anonymous sub but that print still has to run.

The questions print is inside an anonymous sub which gets passed. Yours is an expression in the argument list.

@clamp  "The questions print is inside an anonymoous sub which gets passed. Yours is an expression in the argument list."  -- that is correct.  Which is why I added a comment below, that in the question that print still has to run, even though it is indeed inside an anon sub defitnon.  So I think that this little example is still relevant as it shows that the expression in parens first runs.  Perhaps that's just obvious though...

One of the answers says, that "Perl always evaluates the left of the -> last in a call". This seems to be false for object methods.
While both
sub f { shift->(@_) }
f(sub{ print 'f ' . Data::Dumper::Dumper \@_ });

sub g { $_[0]->(@_) }
g(sub{ print 'g ' . Data::Dumper::Dumper \@_ });

lead to equivalent output
f $VAR1 = [
          sub { "DUMMY" }
        ];
g $VAR1 = [
          sub { "DUMMY" }
        ];

the following
package F {
    sub f {shift->ff(@_)}
    sub ff {print 'F ' . Data::Dumper::Dumper \@_}
}

package G {
    sub g {$_[0]->gg(@_)}
    sub gg {print 'G ' . Data::Dumper::Dumper \@_}
}

(bless {}, 'F')->f;
(bless {}, 'G')->g;

does not
F $VAR1 = [
          bless( {}, 'F' )
        ];
G $VAR1 = [
          bless( {}, 'G' ),
          $VAR1->[0]
        ];

